# Регулярное выражение по всему документу

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Почему не ищет по всему документу, а лишь по одной строчке? Если мне нужно нужно выдернуть между двумя тегами, но от переноса строк избавляться нежелательно.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Справа там где регулряка заканчивается, около флага `g` нажмите мышкой и поставьте дополнительно флаг `s` - single line. без него `.` в выражении означает любой символ _кроме_ перевода строки

Comment: @Mike спасибо, добавил теперь,поиск до \n\n, онлайн работает, а на моем сервере почему то нет, модификторы добавил

Comment: на вашем сервере в каком языке (программе) ?

Comment: @Mike php, preg_match

Comment: хм. обязано работать. вы уверены, что у вас весь текст в одной текстовой переменной, а вы его например не построчно читаете ? Можете еще `m` попробовать, но это немного другое ...

Comment: @Mike, а `m` пробовать как раз не надо. http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Answer (score 0):

Тема регулярок на `php` обширна. Изучить подробно ее можно [в документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php)
Для получения содержимого определенного тега можно воспользоваться **[утверждениями](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php)** - проверками касательно символов, идущих до или после текущей позиции сопоставления, ничего при этом не поглощающими (никакие символы исходного текста не ставятся в соответствие утверждениям). Утверждения бывают двух видов: те, которые анализируют *текст, следующий после текущей позиции* (look ahead), и *идущий перед ней* (look behind).

Утверждения - это такие же подмаски, только обязательно фиксированной длины текста

Утверждения касательно **предшествующего текста**:

```
// Положительное утверждение начинается с (?<=
preg_match("/(?<=<p>).*/","<div><p>Текст </p><strong>жирный</strong></div>"); 
// найдет "Текст </p><strong>жирный</strong></div>"

// Отрицательное утверждение начинается с (?<!
preg_match("/(?<!"k">)(текст.*)/","<div><p class="k">Текст </p><p class="f">текст 2</p></div>")
// найдет "текст 2</p></div>"
```

Утверждения касательно **последующего текста**:

```
// Положительное утверждение начинается с (?=
preg_match("/[^<]*(?=<\/p>)/","<div><p>Текст 12</p><strong>жирный</strong></div>"); 
// Найдет "p>Текст 12"

// Отрицательное утверждение начинается с (?!
preg_match("/<p>[^<]*(?!<\/p>)/","<div><p>Текст 12</p><strong>жирный</strong></div>"); 
// Найдет "<p>Текст 1" - исключит двойку
```

Чтобы расширить поиск по многострочному тексту или спецсимволам (табуляции и т.п.), можно использовать **[экранирующие последовательности](http://php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.escape.php)**

Comment: А к чему все это - там единственная проблема - отсутствие флага single line, про который в вашем ответе кстати ни слова. И кстати в вопросе php в тегах нет, он в целом по регулярным выражениям.

Comment: Добавь /m - чтобы искал по всем строкам

Comment: Чтобы выдернть текст между тегами, при использовании в php используй утверждения
`/(?<=<h1>)[^<>]*(?=<\/h1>)/m`

Comment: А вот и не угадали, `m` влияет только на интерпретацию `^` и `$` в данном случае оно не поможет. Тут нужен `s` что бы `.` обозначала все, включая перевод каретки. А в утверждениях в данном случае особого смысла нет, они только процесс тормозят. А эффект тот же, когда нужная группа выделена в скобках

Comment: И кстати, ваше предложение `/(?<=<h1>)[^<>]*(?=<\/h1>)/m` абсолютно не рабочее для данного в вопросе примера, там же есть другие теги внутри и значит "НЕ <>" не годится

Comment: `<h1>[\t\s\S]*<\/h3>` - возьми это